# How to count the number of spoken syllables in an audio file?

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition

I have many audio files with clean audio and only spoken voice in Mandarin Chinese. I need to estimate of how many syllables are spoken in each file. Is there a tool for OS X, Windows, or Linux that can estimate these?

```
sample01.wav 15
sample02.wav 8
sample03.wav 5
sample04.wav 1
sample05.wav 18
```

As there are many files, command-line or batch-capable software is preferred, e.g.:

```
$ application sample01.wav
15
```

- A solution that uses speech-to-text, then counts the number of characters present would be suitable to.

Comment: I am just wondering how an answer (from @navneet35371) could be rewarded (+450) while this answer is posterior to mine and include only one link that I give in my answer. Seems like unfair no?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I knew the speechrate script solved the problem, but I did not realize it was mentioned in two different posts. When I have more points, I will find some way to award you bounty points.

Comment: That's fine - I could have make it more obvious. And please keep you points for some other useful bounties, I would be happy to help again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The automatic segmentation of speech is an active scientific domain, meaning that there is no method that works perfectly.

In 2009, de Jong and Wempe proposed a method to automatically detect syllables in a human speech signal using [Praat](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/). This methods compares well with man-made segmentation, and has been employed in many third-party scientific studies. You can find a detailed description of the method in their scientific article ([pdf](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BRM.41.2.385)), along with an historical perspective on previously proposed methods. The Praat script per se and a couple of tutorials can be found on a dedicated website ([www - speechrate](https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/)).

You may also be interested in another segmentation algorithm developed by [Harma](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1200027) that has been implemented in Matlab ([Harma Syllable Segmentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29261-harma-syllable-segmentation))

Answer (score 1):

You can use formants to determine this. Each syllable should correspond to a formant. Here is more information on formants:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formants

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest for you

http://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires specific attention and solution for Speech to Text.
I really doubt any free open source library, easily available and serving to purpose will be served.

I have used one but for reverse purpose "text to speech".
Though this is not a free library, i would love to help  just Google "annosoft lipsync"...

```
http://www.annosoft.com/lipsync-sdks
```

This library is available for SDK evaluation as well....